# What does δt mean in this equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, notation, dirac-delta

I am trying to understand [this page](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/pasp/Ideal_String_Struck_Mass.html#sec:struckstring) which comes to the following equation:

$$f_{\mathrm{ext}}(t) = mv_0\delta(t).$$

They are attempting to describe the force being applied to a mass as a momentary excitation impulse.

Force = mass * acceleration

Here we have:

Force = mass * initial-impulse-velocity * $\delta(t)$

So what is $\delta(t)$? I am guessing it must be by necessity an inverse of a time increment. ie. 1/the-time-the-impulse-is-imparted-over.

Is that correct? Is there some concept that explains this?

How do I use $\delta(t)$ in other equations?

I mean, I would have thought you could also say:

$$f_{\mathrm{ext}}(t) = m\frac{\delta(v(t))}{\delta(t)}$$

ie. Force is equal to mass times the rate of change of velocity (acceleration).

How does that relate to the equation:

$$f_{mathrm{ext}}(t) = m\cdot v_0\cdot\delta(t)$$

Wouldn't that mean:

$$f_{\mathrm{ext}}(t) = kg \cdot\frac ms\cdot s = kg\cdot m$$

I mean, isn't $\delta(t)$ an increment of time when you say $\dfrac{\delta(v)}{\delta(t)}$ for example?

I'm having trouble understanding this. Hopefully at least my confusion on the terms makes sense.

What exactly is $\delta(t)$ in this equation?

Comment: impulse could be [Dirac delta "function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: That makes sense. It's an impulse. And Wikipedia says the the units of δ(t) are $s^{-1}$. which would work. So this is not the same "δ" as used in standard differentials but is in fact representing something else - a tiny inverse of time for an impulse to occur over.

Comment: Please note that the Dirac delta "function" is emphatically NOT a function. Given sets $X$ and $Y$, a function is a rule $f$ which assigns to every element $x$ in $X$ an element $f(x)$ in $Y$. Instead, it is what is known as a "distribution," or "generalized function."

Comment: @Math1000:  I agree that it's not a function in the traditional sense; that's why I put the word function in quotation marks

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Of course. I am just reiterating the point because it is a very important one to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), the Dirac delta can be **loosely** thought of as a function on the real line

that is  defined by

$$ \delta (t)=\begin{cases}+\infty ,&t=0\\0,&t\neq 0\end{cases}$$
and which satisfies
$$ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (t)\,dt=1.$$

This is merely a heuristic characterization. The Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense, as no function defined on the real numbers has these properties. The Dirac delta function can be rigorously defined either as a distribution or as a measure.  See the Wikipedia article for more information.